# ANT script : how to exclude several files with ASDOC engine

Tags: ant, flex4.5, asdoc

I want to exclude several files (*_include.as) in my source project, to generate ASDOC :

```
<target name="build-asdoc" depends="manifest">

    <delete dir="${asdoc.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${asdoc.dir}" />        

    <exec executable="${FLEX_HOME}/bin/asdoc.exe" failonerror="false">
                <arg line="-doc-sources '${src.dir}'" />
                <arg line="-doc-sources '${lib.dir}'" />
                <arg line="-external-library-path '${ivy.cache.dir}/org.puremvc.as3/singlecore/swcs'" />
                <arg line="-external-library-path '${ivy.cache.dir}/com.keepcore.calendar/KCCalendar/swcs'" />
                <arg line="-external-library-path '${ivy.cache.dir}/org.as3commons/as3commons-lang/swcs'" />                        
                <arg line="-main-title '${asdoc.mainTitle}'" />
                <arg line="-window-title '${asdoc.windowTitle}'" />
                <arg line="-output '${asdoc.dir}'" />
                <arg line="-footer '${asdoc.footer}'" />
                <arg line="-exclude-sources ?????" />
            </exec>

</target>
```

Thank you very much,

Regards,

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

Use a fileset and a path convert :

```
<fileset dir="${src.dir}" id="src.files">
      <include name="**/*.cpp"/>
    </fileset>

<pathconvert pathsep="," property="excluded.src.files" refid="src.files"/>
```

Now property `${excluded.src.files}` will have your files separated by a space, you can add your own separator etc. according to your program input argument. Then you just pass this with your -exlucde-sources arg to your program and that's it.